# Makefile with unimplemented functions in library

Tags: c, makefile

First of all, I've been searching for an answer here and I haven't been able to find one. If this question is really replicated please redirect me to the right answer and I'll delete it right away. My problem is that I'm making a C library that has a few unimplemented functions in the .h file, that will need to be implemented in the main.c that calls this library. However, there *is* an implemented function in the library that calls them. I have a makefile for this library that gives me "undefined reference to" every function that's not implemented, so the when I try to link the .o s in the main.c file that *does* have those implementations I can't, because the original library wasn't able to compile because of these errors.

My question is, are there any flags that I could put in the makefile so that it will ignore the unimplemented headers or look for them once the library is linked?

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with `make`.  Are you asking how to create a library?

Comment: I apologize. I thought that perhaps there was some Makefile trick that I could use for this instead of function pointers, which is why I asked about it. I stand corrected, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very old-fashioned way of writing a library (but I've worked on code written like that).  It does not work well with shared libraries, as you are now discovering.

#### If you can change the library design

Your best bet is to rearrange the code so that the 'missing functions' are specified as callbacks in some initialization function.  For example, you might currently have a header a bit like:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED

extern int implemented_function(int);
extern int missing_function(int);

#endif
```

I'm assuming that your library contains `implemented_function()` but one of the functions in the library makes a call to `missing_function()`, which the user's application should provide.

You should consider restructuring your library along the lines of:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED

typedef int (*IntegerFunction)(int);

extern int implemented_function(int);
extern IntegerFunction set_callback(IntegerFunction);

#endif
```

Your library code would have:

```
#include "header.h"

static IntegerFunction callback = 0;

IntegerFunction set_callback(IntegerFunction new_callback)
{
    IntegerFunction old_callback = callback;
    callback = new_callback;
    return old_callback;
}

static int internal_function(int x)
{
    if (callback == 0)
        ...major error...callback not set yet...
    return (*callback)(x);
}
```

(or you can use `return callback(x);` instead; I use the old school notation for clarity.)  Your application would then contain:

```
#include "header.h"

static int missing_function(int x);

int some_function(int y)
{
    set_callback(missing_function);
    return implemented_function(y);
}
```

An alternative to using a function like `set_callback()` is to pass the `missing_function` as a pointer to any function that ends up calling it.  Whether that's reasonable depends on how widely used the missing function is.

---

#### If you can't change the library design

If that is simply not feasible, then you are going to have to find the platform-specific options to the code that builds shared libraries so that the missing references do not cause build errors.  The details vary widely between platforms; what works on Linux won't work on AIX and vice versa.  So you will need to clarify your question to specify where you need the solution to work.

Comment: Ok! That's actually perfect. I thought about using function pointers but I wasn't sure if I could just link it a different way. This way is fine though, solved my problem, so thanks very much :)